# "IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present" - when trying to connect application both to mongo and sql

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, spring-boot

We have a Spring application that connects with no problems to a MongoDB, with @Autowire and all the rest.

Now we also need the app to connect *also* to an SQL database.

So we crated an **@entity** class:

```
@Entity(name = "SqlCarRecord")
@Table(name = "Cars")
final public class SqlCarRecord {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
....
```

And a **@repository** interface:

```
@Repository 
public interface SqlCarsRepository extends JpaRepository<SqlCarRecord, Long> {
...
```

And a **@Configuraion** class like the example here https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/

And in the **applicationContext** we added 
`<jpa:repositories base-package="path.to.interface.package" />`

In the **pom.xml** we already have

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and we added:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DataSource (HikariCP) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- adding this to avoid "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal" -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- adding this to avoid "ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.util.CloseableIterator" -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And in the **@Service** class we added:

```
    ....

    @Autowired
    private SqlCarsRepository carsRepository;
```

The project is built successfully, but when we try to run it, we get this error:

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested 
exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel 
must be present!
```

Some of the things We tried:

- change the different versions of spring in the pom,
- we tried to comment some of them,
- we tried to change the interface to extend *CrudRepository*,
- tried to add an empty constructor to the entity and some other things

with no luck.

Will appriciate help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same error message by changing the @SpringBootApplication annotation to this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

If you are using the @EnableAutoConfiguration directly, try this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                                    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

It seems that the root problem is that the Spring Boot is trying to add something that is already on the classpath.

*Most of answer taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30597861/7470360*